# Rails 5 devise_token_auth Can't verify CSRF token authenticity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf-protection

I am working on a Rails 5 api project which is used by mobile client with gem `devise_token_auth` for authorization.

I am clear about what the warning means.

**1st Question:** **CSRF protect should be turned OFF for api(JSON/XML)respond**, correct?

I searched some on web it seems CSRF just happens on web application with cookie. But i read this from [rails api documen](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html)t:

> It's important to remember that XML or JSON requests are also affected >and if you're building an API you should change forgery protection >method in ApplicationController (by default: :exception):
>
> `class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
>     protect_from_forgery unless: -> { request.format.json? }
>   end`

So i still get the warning by adding like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery unless: -> { request.format.json? }
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
end
```

**2nd Question:** If API doesn't need CSRF protection, why

```
protect_from_forgery unless: -> { request.format.json? }
```

doesn't work?

Not sure if i understood something wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

the code should be:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: ->{request.format.json?}
```

You might have to use `null_session` for API, it provides an empty session during request but doesn't reset it completely. Used as default if :with option is not specified.